# In knockout.js an observable function is not updating

Tags: knockout.js

It's probably easiest to understand my question in reference to my jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/TGBBv/9/

Here the top two divs initially show correctly the number of objects in the 'images' observable array. But when one clicks on 'remove image', only the value of the first div updates.

The difference between the two divs is this. The first binds the data directly:

```
<div data-bind="text: images().length"></div>
```

Whereas the second binds the data indirectly:

```
<div data-bind="text: imagesCount"></div>
```

where in the model, `images` and `imagesCount` are specified thus:

```
self.images = ko.observableArray([img1,img2]);
self.imagesCount = ko.observable(self.images().length);
```

I don't understand why the first div updates and the second doesn't - could someone explain it? I have been assuming that the second should update on the basis of this kind of language from the documentation:

> That’s where computed observables come in - these are functions that
>   are dependent on one or more other observables, and will automatically
>   update whenever any of these dependencies change.

Comment: It has to be a function the computed observable, take a look http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at [the right place](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables): you need a computed observable (`ko.computed`) if you want to create an observable based on other observable:

So change your `imagesCount` to a `ko.computed`:

```
self.imagesCount = ko.computed(function(){ return self.images().length; });
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nd3gX/).

Answer (score 1):

[Computed Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

> Computed observables are **functions** that are dependent on one or more other observables, and will automatically update whenever any of these dependencies change.

```
self.imagesCount = ko.computed(function() {
 return self.images().length;
});
```